# Circular Import Strawberry

Tags: python, graphql, fastapi

Hi I am trying to make a GraphQL API using FastAPI and Strawberry and could not figure out how to do this. Essentially here is my problem: I have one model (call it Department) that has a one to many relationship with the Employee model, so that department.employees is the list of all employees belonging to that department. The issue I have is that an employee also has a department, so if I split out the types (see below) I have a circular import. How can I resolve this? Thanks.

**Employee**

```py
import strawberry

from app.models.employee import Employee as EmployeeModel
from app.api.v1.definitions.department import Department
from app.api.v1.definitions.profile import Profile

@strawberry.type
class Employee:
    id: str
    email: str

    instance: strawberry.Private[EmployeeModel]

    @strawberry.field
    def department(self) -> Department:
        return Department.from_instance(self.instance.department)

    @strawberry.field
    def profile(self) -> Profile:
        return Profile.from_instance(self.instance.profile)

    @classmethod
    def from_instance(cls, instance: EmployeeModel):
        return cls(
            instance=instance,
            id=instance.id,
            email=instance.email,
        )
```

**Department**

```py
import strawberry

from app.models.department import Department as DepartmentModel


@strawberry.type
class Department:
    id: int
    name: str
    
    @strawberry.field
    def employees(self) -> "Employee":
        from app.api.v1.definitions.employee import Employee
        return [Employee.from_instance(employee) for employee in self.instance.employees]

    @classmethod
    def from_instance(cls, instance: DepartmentModel):
        return cls(
            id=instance.id,
            name=instance.name,
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was:

```
strawberry.LazyType["Department", "app.api.v1.definitions.department"]
```

Comment: What does this mean? Where did you put this code?

I don't know how to combine a resolver and a lazy type. The resolver needs to instantiate the other model and for that it needs a real reference.